# Why isn't get_serving_url() cropping working correctly?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

According to [the App Engine docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions#Image_get_serving_url) there's a method `get_serving_url` which gives a URL to an image in the blobstore that can then be resized an cropped. So I can take a URL like:

http://lh4.ggpht.com/TgjDT-cPRr6bjrpSVQeILk93o4Ouzjo1ygMB6KpmnCHhyH5vJKKRrqxCD2bC3T09CRIP6h5QFsV_l0hnhio5bN7z

add `=w300-c`:

http://lh4.ggpht.com/TgjDT-cPRr6bjrpSVQeILk93o4Ouzjo1ygMB6KpmnCHhyH5vJKKRrqxCD2bC3T09CRIP6h5QFsV_l0hnhio5bN7z=w300-c

and it should turn into a 300x300 square image.

Except, at the time of writing this post, the image that is returned by the 2nd of the above URLs is horribly malformed.

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo in your url. The documentation says you need to append `=sXX-c` not `=wXX-c`.

In your case you need to use the url http://lh4.ggpht.com/TgjDT-cPRr6bjrpSVQeILk93o4Ouzjo1ygMB6KpmnCHhyH5vJKKRrqxCD2bC3T09CRIP6h5QFsV_l0hnhio5bN7z=s300-c

Comment: Wow. That's strange. I know it definitely used to work with a "w". And the "w" without the -c at the end still resizes it. Is this something that was recently changed?